# NodeJs Sharp Package - Support For PNG Quality

Tags: node.js, png, sharp

I am working on image processing and using sharp node package for it.

I managed to process **crop**, **resize** & **quality** processing for JPEG images.

However, PNG quality processing is a bit tricky.

[sharp docs](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-output/#png) say, png quality processing requires libvips compiled with support for **libimagequant**

I followed [one of the sharp issues](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1793) which deals with similar problem.

However, it started giving error when I was installing node module.

The global installation of libvisp does get picked up by sharp node package during installation but it fails.

P.S. I followed the [this installation process](https://pngquant.org/lib/) to install libimagequant.

**Can someone let me know the proper way to compile libvips with libimagequant so that PNG quality processing can be supported?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer the [home page of same site](https://pngquant.org/), your problem might be solved. There you can see couple of ways and tools available and you can pick any based on your OS